# Rename root directory in wordpress leading to errors

Tags: wordpress, dns, frontend, root

I'm trying to change the name of the root of a wordpress page but receiving errors after I do. I wanna do this because I conducted some updates and want to push them from staging to live, but let me explain:

**Initial state**

1. Domain example.com pointing to folder /staging.example.com/
2. Domain dev-2.example.com pointing to /dev-2.example.com/

**Actions performed**

3. Rename /staging.example.com/ to /example.com/
4. Change DB-settings in wp_options accordingly (siteurl, home)

Currently this is causing multiple issues in the frontend and it happened before. But it also didn't happen before most times I performed such an action.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!
Xandru